# How to make Windows 7 default in grub menu?

Tags: boot, grub2

How to change the label to make Windows 7 to be a default on this screen?

[image: grub menu]

Answer (score 0):

If you edit `/etc/default/grub` and edit two entries, it'll remember the last OS you selected to boot as the default choice for next time.

In `terminal`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

edit in these, near the top of the file...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved     # change this line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true  # add this line
```

the first one is already there, but needs an edit. The second one you'll need to add. Then, still in `terminal`...

```
sudo update-grub
```